# Integrating $\int dx \int dy (x-y)^2 xy \exp(-a(x-y)^2)$

Tags: gaussian-integral

Any useful change of variable possible to make the integration easier ?
$$
\int dx \int dy (x-y)^2 xy \exp(-a(x-y)^2)
$$

Comment: This integral diverges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a rotation:

$$u = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$v = \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}$$

to get the integral

$$\iint_{\Bbb{R}^2} u^2(v^2-u^2)\exp(-2au^2)\:du\:dv$$

which diverges because of the $v$.